# How to analyze packets?

Tags: protocol, packet

I have a packet that I want to analyze which consists 16 bytes. I can produce as much as of these packets needed to analyze.

Even though packet does the same thing on application the data in the packet seems to be changed each time. It works when I record the old packet and use it next time application runs. It also works when first or last 8 bytes are replaced with bytes from previously recorded packets.

My aim is to be able to produce these packets myself. Here's some recorded packets:

```
0xb1, 0xd0, 0x36, 0xe8, 0x1f, 0xdb, 0xc7, 0x36, 0x66, 0x39, 0x17, 0x15, 0xcc, 0xa1, 0x8a, 0x61
0x17, 0x21, 0x6e, 0x45, 0x0d, 0x3f, 0x08, 0x86, 0xed, 0x55, 0x26, 0x19, 0xf6, 0x15, 0x6b, 0xb1
0x08, 0xb9, 0xd7, 0xe9, 0xa8, 0x80, 0xea, 0x8c, 0x18, 0x5e, 0x92, 0xc5, 0xb7, 0x1a, 0xed, 0xf7
0x2a, 0x12, 0x1c, 0x71, 0x36, 0x00, 0xb3, 0x6f, 0xbb, 0x7b, 0x57, 0x65, 0xe5, 0xa7, 0x45, 0xd4
0x17, 0x21, 0x6e, 0x45, 0x0d, 0x3f, 0x08, 0x86, 0xcf, 0x5a, 0x95, 0xaa, 0x41, 0x88, 0xd3, 0xf1
0xb1, 0xd0, 0x36, 0xe8, 0x1f, 0xdb, 0xc7, 0x36, 0x20, 0x68, 0x45, 0x26, 0x2d, 0xce, 0xc8, 0x32
```

Comment: Just to make sure: `B1 D0 36 E8 1F DB C7 36 66 39 17 15 CC A1 8A 61` and `17 21 6E 45 0D 3F 08 86 ED 55 26 19 F6 15 6B B1` do the same thing in the application, and `B1 D0 36 E8 1F DB C7 36 ED 55 26 19 F6 15 6B B1` does the same as well, but changing one random byte doesn't?  Anyway, this sounds like you have to reverse the packet processing function, but if you want to have a (slight!) chance without that, you'd have to provide many more examples.

Comment: Exactly as you said. I've tried to reverse the function but i just don't know enough assembly even though i know exactly where the packet is encrypted. I can provide as much examples as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be the case that it's [CBC-encrypted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) data, with the first field being a nonce. Or one of many other possibilities.

Either way, as Guntram said in his comment above, you'd need to reverse engineer the software to determine how this data is parsed.

Comment: So it's unlikely that i'll get somewhere without reverse engineering the software. Thanks.